# Connected No Internet, Secured

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I have a laptop yesterday everything is fine then after this morning i having a problem with my network. It's connected but No internet.

I try to connect to other networks even on my mobile hotspot still I have same issue even I'm using Wired or network adapter.
I also try to reset network flushdns but Without any luck I still have those error :(

please help

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try reset winsock :

1)Run cmd as admin.

2)netsh winsock reset.

3)restart your laptop and try again

https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/Resetting_Network_Adapter_%28Winsock_Reset%29

Comment: Worked like a charm for me as well.  Can't say I am too impressed with all the answers to this question - not here, but elsewhere - that start out suggesting to reinstall drivers.  Use a flyswatter on a fly, not a crowbar.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**:

STEP-1: Connect with your mobile hotspot.

STEP-2: Troubleshoot your network. Troubleshoot shows the problem at that time.

I also have this problem.
This solution works for me

Comment: I try this solution but Still same issue

Comment: Disable Wi-Fi property in network property and again enable it. And check bios too